# Searching for users?

Tags: feature-request, search, users

When using the handy search functionality that's spread across all StackExchange sites, keywords in questions are the things that are primarily returned based on your search query. What about adding in an additional functionality to the search that adds in an optional query for usernames as well as questions? If this feature already exists, how is it accessed?

Comment: This is supposed to be a two-in-one question, as well as a simultaneous feature request! :)

Comment: @T145 It's best to avoid that, one question per question if possible

Comment: Well, can't hurt to adventurous every once and a while!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [Users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users) tab to search for users.

Use the `is:question` modifier to return only questions in search results.

Answer (score 4):

`user:1234` will search for questions/answers from a particular user

For example this search on stack overflow will show you all the questions/answers from me in the [java] tag. All amazing stuff I can assure you

```
[java] user:2187042
```

[https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+user%3A2187042](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D%20user:2187042)

Comment: Unfortunately `"user:Richard Tingle"` doesn't search for questions asked by Richard Tingle. (No offense, but I haven't memorized your userid yet)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg *Is horrified*, but seriously theres no way it reasonably could. There could be more than one Richard Tingle as display names do not have to be unique

Comment: @RichardTingle So then it could simply filter to all questions by any Richard Tingle...

Comment: @Servy That could be nice behaviour

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to access these searches if you can reach the user's profile page is to click on one of their tags in the tag section. This link will launch a search for that users posts in that tag. For example, clicking the javascript tag in your profile on SO:

[image]

results in this:

[image]

Comment: I'll upvote when I have 15 rep!